Retrieve dataLayer using Robot Framework and Browser Library
Using Robot Framework and Selenium I am able to retrive the datalayer with the following command:
${dataLayer}=  Execute Javascript    return window.dataLayer
how do I get the same results using the Browser Library instead of the Selenium Library?
I already tried with what seems equivalent in the Browser Library:
${dataLayer}=  Evaluate Javascript    return window.dataLayer

but it goes to timeout so I guess I am not using it properly.
I expect to get in ${dataLayer} the window.dataLayer

Browser Library has the similar keyword, Evaluate JavaScript. Is this something that you are looking for?

Thanks, I've already tried it,  let me specify it in the post.

The syntax I was using is wrong, the right one is:
${dataLayer}=  Evaluate JavaScript    ${None}    window.dataLayer

In this way it works as expected.
